Parallel execution with NodeJs and Puppeteer
I'm using NodeJs and Puppeteer to scrap data from a website.
My goal is to run multiple instances of Puppeteer when scraping data.
However, I may be doing something wrong. Because it is running only one instance, and sending multiple data at once.
Here is what my code does:

Open an XLSX file from the computer
Do some processing and then read the file into the memory(a list of numCpfCnpj and numAcordo)
Separate the entries in batches of 5, for multiple processing.
Call the puppeteer to log on to the page and search for the numCpfCnpj.
After searching the numCpfCnpj, should search for numAcordo and continue with the logic.

However, I can't figure out how to run more than one instance. Is it possible with Puppeteer?
Or should I just throw the script in a cloud service (like AWS Lambda) and run multiple instances of without worrying about anything else?
Here is the code that calls the methods:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const handleLogin = async (page, login, password) => {
    await page.goto('https://www.santandernegocios.com.br/portaldenegocios/#/externo');
    await page.waitForSelector('#userLogin__input');
    await page.waitForSelector('#userPassword__input');
    await page.type('#userLogin__input', login);
    await page.type('#userPassword__input', password);
    await page.focus('#userPassword__input');
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
};

const searchAndNavigate = async (page, cpfCnpj) => {
    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="inputSearch"]');

    // Ensure cpfCnpj is a string
    if (typeof cpfCnpj !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('cpfCnpj must be a string');
    }

    await page.type('input[name="inputSearch"]', cpfCnpj);

  
    await page.waitForFunction(
        (selector, text) => {
            const input = document.querySelector(selector);
            return input && input.value === text;
        },
        {},
        'input[name="inputSearch"]',
        cpfCnpj
    );

    await page.focus('input[name="inputSearch"]');
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
};

const clickMenuLink = async (page, menuTexts) => {
    await page.evaluate(menuTexts => {
        const sessionMenu = document.querySelector('div.session-menu');
        if (sessionMenu) {
            const ul = sessionMenu.querySelector('ul');
            if (ul) {
                for (let text of menuTexts) {
                    const link = Array.from(ul.querySelectorAll('li a')).find(anchor => anchor.textContent.trim() === text);
                    if (link) {
                        link.click();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, menuTexts);
};

const processXlsxFile = async (filePath) => {
    const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath);
    const sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { header: 1 });

    const rows = data.slice(1); // Skip header row
    const groupedEntries = [];
    const groupSize = 5;

    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i += groupSize) {
        groupedEntries.push(rows.slice(i, i + groupSize).map(row => ({
            numCpfCnpj: String(row[0]),  // Ensure it's a string
            numAcordo: String(row[1])    // Ensure it's a string
        })));
    }

    return groupedEntries;
};


const processEntries = async (page, entries, menuTexts) => {
    await Promise.all(entries.map(async (entry) => {
        try {
            console.log(entry.numCpfCnpj);
            await searchAndNavigate(page, entry.numCpfCnpj);
            await clickMenuLink(page, menuTexts);
            console.log(`Processed: ${entry.numCpfCnpj} - ${entry.numAcordo}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error processing ${entry.numCpfCnpj} - ${entry.numAcordo}:`, error);
        }
    }));
};

const runPuppeteer = async (filePath, login, password, menuTexts) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        await handleLogin(page, login, password);
        const entries = await processXlsxFile(filePath);
        
        // Process each group of entries with a limit of 5 simultaneous tasks
        for (const group of entries) {
            // Process each group with a maximum of 5 simultaneous tasks
            const chunkSize = 5;
            for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i += chunkSize) {
                const chunk = group.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
                await processEntries(page, chunk, menuTexts);
            }
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
};

module.exports = { runPuppeteer };

Thanks a lot. If any additional information is needed I'll reply as soon as I see the notification.

Each instance of puppeteer can only handle one page at a time.  Remember that it's actually running a copy of Chrome in the background.  Each tab can only process one site at a time.  So, you'd need multiple instances of puppeteer here.  What are you going to do with the results?  Right now, you're just clicking buttons.

I do have a processing logic after clicking the buttons, of course.
Before doing this, i've done a "single file" with all the content and was running one entry only. Then, after getting it to work i made an HTML page for loading an file, clicking on an button to run, etc.
I know each instance of puppeteer can only handle one page. Its the same case as selenium, of course. My main goal is to run multiple instances of the code (like opening 5 puppeteer instances and scrap 5 items).

OK, but your current code doesn't do that.  You start one puppeteer, and then spin off N tasks using that one instance simultaneously.  That won't work.  Also, the word is "scrape", not "scrap", which as a verb means "trash".

The chunks are being processed serially because the for loop that builds the chunks awaits processEntries() for each chunk, at each turn of the loop.
Here's a little reorg that teases out the chunk-ing, and puts the puppeteer work for a chunk in a single function. It runs all of them at once with Promise.all().
(Didn't compile this, let alone test it, but hopefully you get the gist):
const runChunk = async (chunk, login, password, menuTexts) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await handleLogin(page, login, password);

  try {
    return await processEntries(page, chunk, menuTexts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
};


const runPuppeteer = async (filePath, login, password, menuTexts) => {
  const entries = await processXlsxFile(filePath);
  const chunks = [];

  for (const group of entries) {
    const chunkSize = 5;
    for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i += chunkSize) {
      const chunk = group.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }
  }

  const promises = chunks.map(chunk => runChunk(chunk, login, password, menuTexts));
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  // do whatever with results ...
};

